# Get nth highest salary

Tags: mysql

I want to write a SQL query to get the nth highest salary from the `Employee` table.

```
+----+--------+
| Id | Salary |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 100    |
| 2  | 200    |
| 3  | 300    |
+----+--------+
```

What have I tried?

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  RETURN (
      # Write your MySQL query statement below.
      SELECT Salary
        FROM Employee
        ORDER BY Salary desc
        Limit N,1
  );
END
```

Problem:
I want to return row N-1 not N as rows start from 0. I tried to set a variable but it didn't work,

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
SET M=N-1;
  RETURN (
      # Write your MySQL query statement below.
      SELECT Salary
        FROM Employee
        ORDER BY Salary desc
        Limit M,1
  );
END
```

Comment: If you want to write a query, why are you writing a function?

Comment: @Strawberry: I am practicing on leetcode. Their problem had a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just decrement the variable:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  set n = n - 1;
  RETURN (
      # Write your MySQL query statement below.
      SELECT Salary
        FROM Employee
        ORDER BY Salary desc
        Limit n, 1
  );
END;
```

if you must use separate var, declare it first:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  declare m int;
  set m = n - 1;
  RETURN (
      # Write your MySQL query statement below.
      SELECT Salary
        FROM Employee
        ORDER BY Salary desc
        Limit m, 1
  );
END;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/MTX35568)

Answer (score 0):

select DISTINCT salary from employee e1 where 2 = (select count(DISTINCT salary) from employee e2 where e1.salary <= e2.salary);

where 2 = number. You can find any highest salary from employee table. like 3rd then replace 2 with 3.

Answer (score 0):

This will also take into consideration the scenario where there is a null value or 2 same highest salaries

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
declare m int;
set m = n-1;
  RETURN (SELECT DISTINCT Salary AS getNthHighestSalary
      FROM Employee
      ORDER BY Salary DESC
      LIMIT m, 1

  );
END
```